# Does the carboxyl group count as a branched chain

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds

Do carboxylic acids (or any compound with a carbonyl group) count as a branch chained organic compound due to the C=O? Or does it need a carbon - carbon branch?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In organic chemistry, the terminology of *branched* vs. *unbranched* is generally used to refer to the structure of the hydrocarbon skeleton of a molecule. Hence, heteroatomic functional groups are usually not relevant. The structure in your question is therefore *unbranched*. For an authoritative reference, see the relevant sections of the [IUPAC blue book](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_5.htm).